# use aggregate functions in the WHERE clause (Neo4j)

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

How do I select all nodes that are connected to node(2) [from] with more than one path?

```
START from=node(2)
MATCH p=from-->to
where count(p) > 1 
return from,to
```

To Neo4J team : Any plans to implement Count/Having functions? 
great job so far with the product!

Comment: You should post your answer below and then accept it so that this question won't show up on the unanswered list. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

actually found the solution combining the 'WITH' keyword

```
START from=node(*) 
MATCH p=from-->to 
WITH from as from , to as to, count(p) as paths 
WHERE paths >1 
RETURN to,paths
```